# using one of the ouput parameter of a function oracle PL/SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I have an ORACLE Function with the below signature.

```
Function function1(parameter1 in number,
              parameter2 in number,
              parameter3 in number,
              parameter4 out number,
              parameter5 out varchar(20),
              parameter6 out varchar(20))
             RETURN number is
```

I want use this function in a SQL like this,

```
Select parameter5 
from table1 ti 
where function1(t1.parameter1,t1.parameter2,t1.parameter3)
```

How can I access the output parameter5 in my Select statement? As I want to perform the above select operations in bulk , I am not comfortable using a variable and looping through the resultset.

I dont want use an array as I have to perform few operations in bulk with above SQL Query.

Thanks in Advance!

Cheers,
Dwarak

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you need both parameter5 and the number returned, so maybe it would be better if you create a type and retun it instead.

something like this:

```
create type res_type as object
(
rc number,
parameter5 varchar2(20)
);

Function function1(parameter1 in number,
              parameter2 in number,
              parameter3 in number,
              parameter4 out number,
              parameter5 out varchar(20),
              parameter6 out varchar(20))
             RETURN res_type is
```

UPDATE:

Then in your select you can do something like this:

```
select function1(t1.parameter1,t1.parameter2,t1.parameter3).parameter5 
from table1 ti 
where function1(t1.parameter1,t1.parameter2,t1.parameter3).rc = ....
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't directly, but you could put a wrapper function around it, something like:

```
function function1_wrap(parameter1 in number,
    parameter2 in number,
    parameter3 in number)
    return varchar2 is
declare
    rc number;
    parameter4 number;
    parameter5 out varchar(20);
    parameter6 out varchar(20);
begin
    rc := function1(parameter1, parameter2, parameter3, parameter4, parameter5);
    return parameter5;
end;
```

This might not scale well for bulk operations though; you may be better off trying to replicate how the function is getting the value and combining that into your select, instead of calling the function lots of times. You can drop the parts that find values for parameters 4 and 6, for a start.

Comment: Thanks for this.it was a real quick win.. :)

Answer (score -1):

you can use subquery something like below,

select * from (Select t1.parameter1, t1.parameter2, t1.parameter3 function1(t1.parameter1,t1.parameter2,t1.parameter3) func_result from table1 t1) where func_result=1

Comment: How does that get the value for `parameter5`?